# Add images from UIImagePickerViewController to UICollectionView inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uiimagepickercontroller

At first, sorry for my long question.
I'm creating an custom UITableViewCell with UICollectionView inside it. Whenever users select this cell, UIImagePickerController will appear, and now I wanna pass all selected images from UIImagePickerController into UICollectionView inside my custom cell. 
I was completed to show image picker and now my problem is display selected images in collection view.
How can I make it?
My code:

`SHImageUploadCell.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class SHImageUploadCell;
@protocol SHImagUploadDelegate<NSObject>
@optional
- (void)closeImage:(SHImageUploadCell*)cell;
@end
@interface SHImageUploadCell : UICollectionViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgUpload;
@property (strong,nonatomic) id<SHImagUploadDelegate> delegate;
@property(nonatomic) int imageIndex;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *bugImage;

@end
```

`SHImageUploadCell.m`

```
#import "SHImageUploadCell.h"

@implementation SHImageUploadCell
- (IBAction)bntDeleteImageClick:(id)sender {


    NSDictionary* userInfo = @{@"index": @(self.imageIndex)};

    NSLog(@"%d", self.imageIndex);
    if (_delegate) {
        [_delegate closeImage:self];
    }
}

@end
```

`MyCustomCell.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SHPhotoPickerViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *photoCollection;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *listImage;
@end
```

`MyCustomCell.m`

```
#import "SHPhotoPickerViewCell.h"
#import "SHImageUploadCell.h"

@interface SHPhotoPickerViewCell ()<UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, SHImagUploadDelegate>

@end

@implementation SHPhotoPickerViewCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    // Initialization code
    [self.photoCollection registerClass:[SHImageUploadCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"selectedCell"];
    [self.photoCollection registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"SHImageUploadCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"selectedCell"];
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return self.listImage.count;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    SHImageUploadCell *uploadCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"uploadCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    uploadCell.imgUpload.image = [UIImage imageWithData: self.listImage[indexPath.row]];
    uploadCell.imageIndex = (int)indexPath.row;
    uploadCell.delegate=self;
    return uploadCell;
}

@end
```

Handle cell select:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (indexPath.row == 4){
   UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
   imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
   imagePickerController.delegate = self;
   [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
  }
}
```

UIImagePickerController delegate:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    SHPhotoPickerViewCell *photoPickerCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.pickerCellIndexPath.row inSection:1]];
    UIImage *image = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    image = [SHHelper resizeImageWithImage:image toSize:CGSizeMake(480, 320)];
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.7);
    photoPickerCell.listImage = [NSMutableArray new];
    [photoPickerCell.listImage addObject:imageData];

    [photoPickerCell.photoCollection reloadData];

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

    }];


}
```

Comment: you need to add url in self.listImage then reload your tableview and collectionview

Comment: you need to save this image ?

Comment: Have you set collectionview `datasource` and `delegate` to tableViewCell?

Comment: @KKRocks No, I don't need to save images, just select them and upload to server.

Comment: @Rishab Yes I am

Answer (score 0):

Try this  :

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    id object = [listImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]]) {
        uploadCell.imgUpload.image = (UIImage *)object;
    }
    else{
       uploadCell.imgUpload.image = [UIImage imageWithData: object];
    }

       return uploadCell;
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [listImage addObject:image]; // here add image which you selected
     // reload tableview
     // reload collection view
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

    }];


}
```

Comment: Nothing change. It still crash when I'm selected image:
`[UITableViewCell listImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcd3b897c00`

Comment: At `[photoPickerCell.photoCollection reloadData];` line

Comment: you cant reload using cell.collection  . remove that line. is there one collection view or more ?

Comment: or only reload tableview.

Comment: I must say you are getting wrong cell. So first you need to check the cell type. Because there is "indexPath.row == 4" on didSelectRowAtIndexPath Method,  but you are using "section: 1" on didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method.

Comment: I'm just using one collection view in my cell. I was checked and the problem isn't in `reloadData`. It crash when I'm init the `listImage` array and add `imageData` for it.

Comment: is listImage collectionView's datasource array ?

Comment: @krunal my table view have 3 section, and this cell in section 1 at indexPath.row == 4. What I'm wrong?

Comment: This is correct answer you need to debug your code .while you image to listimage .

Comment: @KKRocks yes, it is.

Comment: check that image is nil or not nil while adding to array ?

Comment: Because you need to check "self.pickerCellIndexPath.row" this variable value because this may be different rather than expecting.